# show/hide javascript function

Tags: javascript, behavior

The following javascriot function shows/hides a contact form. When using function in a stand alone html page the form is hidden by default. When I implement the function in my website the  function behavior is reversed and the form is not hidden by default.

Can someone with javascript experience advise how to reverse the show/hide bevavior of the function below.

Thanks in advance.

```
</script>

<!-- Show/Hide Contact Form  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //showHide function 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {

            //get collapse content selector
            var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');

            //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
            var toggle_switch = $(this);
            $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {

                if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                    toggle_switch.html('Show Form');
                } else {
                    toggle_switch.html('Hide Form');
                }

            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure this code works for show / hide? please share jsfiddle

Comment: If the form starts as visible or block, you will either have to set the visibility to hidden or the display to none using css to make this your default value for the form...is this what you currently have in your css?

Comment: Post here the HTML code.

Comment: Since you are already using jquery scrap what you have and just use the built in show and hide functions. http://api.jquery.com/show/ and corresponding https://api.jquery.com/hide/.

Comment: Set your display as none of class `.nav-toggle` in start
then it will get toggle as and form will set to `display:block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to answer if you'd provided HTML of your form... Okay, I hope you will figure out the solution:

Look at the value of href attribute if the toggle link, it should look like '#something' and then just edit the css file and add the following line at the bottom:

```
#something { display: none }
```

So, make sure you replace `something` with the actual value from the toggle link.

Comment: I did figure it out and you are correct. Thank you!